# How to Bind NameValueCollection For DataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

What kind of collection I should use to convert NameValue collection to be bindable to GridView? When doing directly it didn't work.

```
NameValueCollection GetCollection1()
        {
            NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
            collection.Add("Sam", "Dot Net Perls");
            collection.Add("Bill", "Microsoft");
            collection.Add("Bala", "White House");
            collection.Add("Samy", "IBM");

            return collection;
        }



<DataGrid Name="dgCollection" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

dgCollection.ItemsSource = GetCollection1();
```

[image]

Is Any custom control supports for this kind of Collection as Like SfDataGrid, RadGrid, Xceed.DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to show a collection in a datagrid you should bind the collection to the datagrid.
This can be done by binding the `ItemSource` property of the Datagrid. It can be binded in code behind like this

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Customer.GetSampleCustomerList();
```

If you want to bind the values of the collection in the XAML. You should set the GetCollection1 to a property instead of a return method.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgCollection" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemSource="{Binding GetCollection1"}>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Key}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

See the link for information about the [ItemSource property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc189398(v%3Dvs.95))

For displaying the data you should make use of the DisplayMemberPath property.

Comment: Already set it in the Code behind `dgCollection.ItemsSource = GetCollection1();`

Comment: DataGridTextColumn doesn't have the Property to set the DisplayMemberPath, This property is avail only for the DataGridComboBox Column

Comment: Any obligations to switch from a NameValueCollection to a Dictionary?

Comment: No my intention is to use NameValueCollection only